# How to evalute string value as a formula in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have string value like below in excel in column A. Now I need to evaluate it in column B and has to get result like below.

Column A: CONCATENATE("32 panel ", CHAR(32) ,"Soft touch", CHAR(32) ," bladder", CHAR(32) ,"Hanging")

Column B: 32 panel  Soft touch  bladder Hanging

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you use `" "` instead of Char(32) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the text in cell A1, and you want the result of this in B1

1. Go to Formulas Define Name
2. Choose a name (eg Answer)
3. In the Refers to box, type =EVALUATE(A1)
4. Click OK
5. In Cell B1, type = Answer

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Range("B1").Formula = "=" + Range("A1").Value

ie Assign the formula in cell A1 to cell B1.